# Will ModelMapper create intermediate objects?

Tags: modelmapper

From the example in the documentation...

map().customer.setName(source.getPerson().firstName);

If "customer" does not exist (is null) will ModelMapper create a new Customer object and setCustomer automatically, or do I have to create it beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

ModelMapper will create intermediate objects for you, including `customer` in that example.